# Nullable DateTime List to Non Nullable DateTime List

Tags: c#

I have a list of nullable date times. I need to filter it down to a non-nullable DateTime list by excuding the null values.

```
var d = NullableDateTimeList;
??//var nonNullableList = d.Where(p => p.DateX.HasValue).Select(p => p.Datex);
```

How do I go about doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very close, just add the `.Value` property when selecting the nullable `DateTime`:

```
var nonNullableList = d.Where( p => p.DateX.HasValue )
    .Select( p => p.DateX.Value )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to select the `Vaue` from the `Nullable<DateTime>` before you call `ToList()`:

```
List<DateTime> nonNulls = NullableDateTimeList
    .Where(d => d.DateX.HasValue)
    .Select(d => d.DateX.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just select the `.Value`

```
var nonNullableList = d.Where(p => p.DateX.HasValue).Select(p => p.DateX.Value);
```